# Is concept of Bipartite Graph relevant only for Connected Graph?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Is concept of Bipartite Graph relevant only for Connected Graph?
For Example : 
4 vertices and just 2 Edges i.e. one from node 1 to node 2, and the another from node 2 to node 3.  So, is this Disconnected Graph also a Bipartite Graph? Or Bipartite graph deals with Connected Graphs only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bipartite graph only requires that the vertex set can be partitioned into two disjoint sets, say $A$ and $B$, such that every edge in $E$ connects a vertex from one of the sets, to the other. You can have isolated points. If one denotes the bipartite graph by $(A,B,E)$, then formally you will have a different bipartition depending on if you place an isolated vertex in $A$ or in $B$.

Comment: So, the one example I mentioned in the question is a Bipartite Graph, as it have one isolated vertex.

Comment: @RudrakshaBaplawat Yes. Let node $1$ and $3$ be in vertex set $A$, and node $2$ in $B$, then place node $4$ in whichever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

No, the definition works perfectly well for a disconnected graph. A graph is bipartite if and only if each of the connected components is bipartite.

Comment: and since an isolated vertex is also a Bipartite graph, the example I mentioned above is Bipartite.